# TensorFlow v10 reformulate sigmoid cross entropy loss to work given sigmoid?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Reading the TF guide for [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) one passes the `logits` and `labels` to the function, after which the `sigmoid` operation is applied to `logits`. To avoid overflow in `exp(-x)` when `x < 0` they reformulate the function to:

```
max(x, 0) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-abs(x)))
```

This is all well and good, however it may be the case where you want the output of your network to have the sigmoid transformation and use [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) without having the loss apply the sigmoid again. How would one reformulate this for that while avoiding overflow for `exp(-x)` with `x < 0`?

Answer (score 0):

> it may be the case where you want the output of your network to have
>   the sigmoid transformation and use
>   tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits without having the loss apply
>   the sigmoid again.

If I am not wrong you are trying to give the logits a value processed by a sigmoid activation. A processed value bounded by (0, 1). I don't think the x would ever be < 0. It seems not reasonable put a value between 0 and 1 to the logits since the sigmoid of that value is always between 0.5 and sigmoid(1), which means for your negative labels the model tries to train them as 0 but the minimun value from the model is 0.5. The loss always exists(as log(1+exp(0.5))) for the negative samples and can never be minimized.

Comment: I believe it depends on the problem at hand. In a multi-class, multi-label problem a sigmoid cross entropy loss function is often preferred over the softmax variant and I believe this is because softmax makes the probability of a label dependent on those of the other labels.  So a negative x value, going into the sigmoid is transformed to a value (probability) close to zero. So I want the output of my network to be a sigmoid activation function. However, as you state and hence my question, I do not want to take the sigmoid again in the loss function, sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits